# Print a WebPage that isn't shown

Tags: html, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

How can I print a page that isn't showed on a window/widget?
Qt Code:
Switch view

```
QPainter painter(printer);
m_webView->page()->setViewportSize(m_pageToPrint->mainFrame()->contentsSize());
painter.scale(scale, scale);
m_pageToPrint->mainFrame()->render(&painter);
```

To copy to clipboard, switch view to plain text mode 
This is the code used( now is converted from m_webView to m_pageToPrint) to print the page from webView, which is showed, but the code for m_pageToPrint which isn't showed, only loaded with the HTML to be printed? The result of the above code is a white page in the PrinterPreviewer.
This is the code to load the html and after to call the previewer:
Qt Code:
Switch view

```
m_pageToPrint->mainFrame()->setHtml(finalHTML);
m_printPreviewDialog->exec();
```

To copy to clipboard, switch view to plain text mode 
finalHTML is a valid html code.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to print my HTML report page:

**reportprint.h**

```
class ReportPrint : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        ReportPrint(QObject *parent = 0);
        void printHTML(QUrl url);
    private:
        QWebView m_webView;
        QPrinter m_printer;
        QPrintPreviewDialog *m_preview;
    protected slots:
        void printReady(bool enable);
        void paintRequested(QPrinter*printer);
}
```

**reportprint.cpp**

```
ReportPrint::ReportPrint(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent) {
    connect(&m_webView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this, SLOT(printReady(bool)));
}

void ReportPrint::printHTML(QUrl url) {
    m_webView.page()->settings()->clearMemoryCaches();
    // here I point to directory which contains printed html file so the engine can found css files
    QUrl base = QUrl::fromLocalFile(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "templates/");         
    m_webView.setHtml(url,base);
}

void ReportPrint::printReady(bool enable) {
    if(print_to_default_printer) {
        QString pn = QPrinterInfo::defaultPrinter().printerName();
        m_printer.setPrinterName(pn);
        m_printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
        m_webView.print(&m_printer);
    } else if(print_with_preview) {
        m_preview = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&p_printer);                 
        connect(m_preview,SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter*)),
                this,SLOT(paintRequested(QPrinter*)));
    }

}

void ReportPrint::paintRequested(QPrinter *printer) {
    m_printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
    m_webView.print(printer);
    m_preview->deleteLater();
}
```